# Ajax database insert

Tags: ajax

Hi Have Start A new Program That Need To update user_points row by ajax 
my code is

```html
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_SESSION['user']))
{
 header("Location: index.php");
}

$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=".$_SESSION['user']);
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
// Retrieve data from database 
$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']);
$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET user_points = user_points +'$user_points' WHERE user_id = " . $_SESSION['user']);
// close MySQL connection 
mysql_close();
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL= http://mywebsite/login-registration/home.php">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" />

</head>
<body bgcolor="#ffffff">


</body>
</html>
```

How can i setup the correct query to send the data to database i want to update the user_points by ajax the info its send from other app this app go to send the user_points by ajax to the php and php go to update the user points

Comment: on error log it s come that

Comment: i habe been look up on error log file and its come that error

Comment: [17-Mar-2016 14:25:22 Europe/Lisbon] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/publiadd/public_html/mywebsite/login-registration/home.php on line 20

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
session_start();
include_once 'dbconnect.php';

if(!isset($_POST['user']))
{
    header("Location: index.php");
    die();
}

$user_id = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['user']);
$res=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_id=$user_id");
$userRow=mysql_fetch_array($res);
// Retrieve data from database 

$sql = mysql_query("UPDATE `users` SET user_points = user_points +1 WHERE user_id = $user_id");
// close MySQL connection 
mysql_close();
?>
```

`$user_ponts` isn't defined in your code. Further you should use the escaped `$user_id` in your SQL statements. Additionally you should use `die` after the header redirection to prevent the rest of the code from being executed.
Further $_SESSION is probably not what you want to use for an ajax call. You could use $_POST instead.

Comment: tank you for have replay well what i need i need to send from an app by ajax to the database user_points

Comment: the database is users and i have 3 rows there 1=user_id 2=user_name 3= user_points

Comment: well i have change the code and now its give me that error [17-Mar-2016 14:56:09 Europe/Lisbon] PHP Warning:  mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home/publiadd/public_html/mywebsite/login-registration/home.php on line 20

Comment: You could send an ajax request with the parameters user_id and user points and the get the points from $_Post like the id. The ajax call you have to use depends on the language you're using in your app

Comment: well my app it use html5 and i call by "http://bitcoinrotator.publiadds.org.pt/login-registration/sendajaxdata.php?user_points="&cach